# CoffeeScript - Applying a class via loop?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I've been experimenting a little bit and have run into a few occasions where it seems to make sense to apply a CS "class" via a loop.

For example:

```
if ($areas = $('.itemParent')).length >= 1
    class SomeClass
        constructor: (el) ->
            @$parent = el
            @$overflow = el.find('.overflow')
            @$items = @$overflow.find('.item')

            @max = @$items.length - 1
            @current = 0

        # Gets us to an area
        goToItem: (i) ->
            @$overflow.animate
                scrollLeft: @$items.eq(i).position().left
            , 450, 'easeInOutQuad'

        # Binds each item
        bindItems: ->
            @$parent.find('.item').bind 'click tap', (e) =>
                el = $(e.target).parents('.item')

                @$items.removeClass('active')
                el.addClass('active')

                @goToItem(el.index())
            @

    # Iterate and apply the structure to all areas
    $areas.each -> 
        area = new SomeClass($(@))
        area.bindItems()
```

It just seems more structured than binding them all "globally".. Is this a poor way to do this?

Comment: `few occasions where it seems to make sense` Please list these occasions.

Comment: Multiple 'slideshows' on a page, for example.

Comment: You mean multiple instances of the slide show class?

Comment: Basically. Like if I have ".slideshow" on a website in multiple areas, and they all have different slides/pagers/navs (but are similarly structured). Applying the class would autoplay/bind/etc on each. 

Just seems like a DRY approach?

Comment: That's fine but why do you need to re-declare the class functions each time too?

Comment: Well in the above example, it's the same thing. Just takes each element and binds them all - considering you can't just do, say, Slideshow = new Slideshow($('.slideshow')) because it wouldn't be respective of each instance.. Make sense?

Comment: This somehow feels like #ifdef ing with the C-preprocessor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea behind `Coffeescript` classes is to define them globally or in modules.

Defining a class inside of another type of scope is kind of missing the point.

`Coffeescript` classes encourage a more `ruby`-esque view of classes as being separate from instances while retaining the power you get from being able to apply them as you see fit.

To put it simply, it's best to use `Coffeescript` classes at the top level or by exporting and requiring them from modules.